# Oracle SQL how to get around group by clause within a case when

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having trouble returning unique records due to having to use the GROUP BY for a particular field because it is within the CASE WHEN clause.  Here is the query:

```
SELECT L.COLUMN1                 AS COL1,
ROUND(L.COLUMN2 * 1000) AS COL2,
CASE
  WHEN L.COLUMN3 >= 20 AND L.COLUMN4 = 3
  THEN 'Y'
  ELSE 'N'
END AS COMPLETED,
CASE
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT VC.COLUMN5)= 0
  OR (COUNT(DISTINCT VC.COLUMN5) > 0
  AND SUM(VC.COLUMN10)              =SUM(VC.COLUMN11))
  THEN 'Y'
  WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT VC.COLUMN5) > 0      
  AND SUM(VC.COLUMN10)             <>SUM(VC.COLUMN11)
  AND VC.COLUMN8 IN (SELECT S.CODE_ID FROM TABLE5 S
  WHERE S.COLUMN6 = 'C' AND S.COLUMN7 = 'SVS')
  THEN 'S'
  ELSE 'N'
END AS YNS,
NVL(
CASE
 WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT LL.COLUMN12)> 0
 THEN 'N'
 ELSE 'Y'
 END,'Y') AS YN
FROM TABLE1 L
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 VC
 ON L.COLUMN1 = VC.COLUMN5
 LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 LL
 ON L.COLUMN9 = LL.COLUMN9
 AND LL.COLUMN1 = L.COLUMN1
WHERE L.OIIN='O'
 AND L.COLUMN3 < 90
GROUP BY L.COLUMN1,
 L.COLUMN2 ,
 L.COLUMN3,
 L.COLUMN4, 
 VC.COLUMN8;
```

The part here which is causing the duplicates is

```
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT VC.COLUMN5) > 0      
  AND SUM(VC.COLUMN10)             <>SUM(VC.COLUMN11)
  AND VC.COLUMN8 IN (SELECT S.CODE_ID FROM TABLE5 S
  WHERE S.COLUMN6 = 'C' AND S.COLUMN7 = 'SVS')
  THEN 'S'
```

because it is having the GROUP BY VC.COLUMN8 at the end.  If I remove the group by then I get the error that this is not a group by expression.  How can I remove the group by and only return unique records for COL1 in the table where i still get an "S" populated if any record for COL1 fits the below requirement?

```
WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT VC.COLUMN5) > 0      
  AND SUM(VC.COLUMN10)             <>SUM(VC.COLUMN11)
  AND VC.COLUMN8 IN (SELECT S.CODE_ID FROM TABLE5 S
  WHERE S.COLUMN6 = 'C' AND S.COLUMN7 = 'SVS')
  THEN 'S'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that in the query that does not have VC.COLUMN8 in the GROUP BY clause, there are potentially multiple values for VC.COLUMN8 per output row of the query. The query cannot therefore resolve whether VC.COLUMN8 is in the list defined by the subquery.

You'll have to resolve this logical issue in order to know how to proceed -- do you mean to test whether there is at least one value for VC.COLUMN8 that is in the subquery, or that all of them must be in the subquery?